# TortoiseSVN isn't ignoring directory present in svn:ignore

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, ignore, svnignore

I'm trying to ignore a complete directory with TortoiseSVN.

First here a glimps of the start of 'Check for modifications'.

[image: Check for modifications]

There is only files that are in 'bin' directory and all are 'unversioned'.

But here is the catch for the properties of the directory are these :

[image: props]

[image]

And further more i added the bin file in the global ignore list of Tortoise SVN ...

[image]

I don't know why it's still showing while other directories like 'target' are all well taken care of...

Thanks in advance if someone has a idea.

Comment: What folder does that `svn:ignore` belong to? A typical setup would be to actually include `bin` in the repository but keep it empty by setting its `svn:ignore` property, but then the value should be like `pom.xml src` or simply `*`.

Comment: first, thanks for your answer.
the svn-ignore property is on parent folder like 'parent/bin'.
The thing i don't understand is why it's working on 'target' folder but not on 'bin' folder.
The 2 directories are exactly at the same level with same config :/

Comment: I'm clueless then. I've never used global ignore patterns but `svn:ignore` looks good to me.